# Hibernate - HQL help to optimize query

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a HQL query like so:

```
Select  
... (around 40 items)...
from 
ATable a 
left outer join a.subA SubA 
left outer join a.subB SubB 
left outer join a.Names Names 
left outer join Names.Addresses Addresses 
left outer join Names.Phones Phones 
left outer join a.Roles Roles 
where 
a.aType.someType in ('...') 
and (Names.id.FKey in('...') or Names.id.FKey is null)  
and upper(a.pin) like upper('some%')  
and upper(Names.lastName) like upper('Some%')  
order by  a.pin    asc
```

For some reason this times out but the query generated by hibernate (taken from logs) takes 5 seconds to execute while using Toad. I am a novice in hibernate. I am thankful to any help to optimize this Thanks.

Comment: http://hungred.com/useful-information/ways-optimize-sql-queries/

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that I could suggest are:

1] Avoid using 'IN' clause.
2] Avoid using order by if it is not necessary.

Amit :)